# How can I set up a server to listen for wireless and wired interfaces at the same time?

Tags: wireless, networking, server, network-manager

I've looked for an answer for several hours now and couldn't find it.

I'm setting up a development server which should be accessible to wireless and wired networks at the same time.

A wireless client may ask for resources on the wired network, but at the same time a wired client may want to access the service via the wired connection.

I can only seem to get one of the interfaces to respond to pings/requests with the tomcat instance running on that machine.

It used to work perfectly a few weeks ago, but I had automatic updates turned on (new to linux) and I think network manager has been updated and now it's configured to block this functionality.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the server by wire to a wired/wireless router and the router will take care of everything.  If the server has both wired and wireless, turn off the wireless (or if you need redundancy, bond the wireless and wired connection.)

Comment: My problem is I need to have the server answering on both networks.
If I would do what you ask, it'll stop working on the wireless network.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, you can only have one default gateway...  You would need to set up manual routing on the server (in fact turning it into a router.)  I'm not saying it's *impossible*, I'm trying to tell you it's just a bad idea.  Why do you want to do this?